# File is opened, but not sure when it closes

Tags: c#

Here is a fragment of my code:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(templatePath, outputPath, true);

using(var output = WordprocessingDocument.Open(outputPath, true))
{
    Body updatedBodyContent = new Body(newWordContent.DocumentElement.InnerXml);
    output.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body = updatedBodyContent;
    output.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    response.Content = new StreamContent(
        new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = outputPath;
}
```

The file in the outputPath location does not initially exist. It gets created in line 1. On line 8 it breaks - it says the file is being used.

I'm not where the error is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error thrown by line 8?

Comment: The process cannot access the file 'path\to\file\temp.docx' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: The file is already opened by 

using (WordprocessingDocument output = WordprocessingDocument.Open(outputPath, true))

and then you try to reopen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to finish with the `WordprocessingDocument` and let it close before trying to open the file. This ought to work:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(templatePath, outputPath, true);

using (WordprocessingDocument output = 
       WordprocessingDocument.Open(outputPath, true))
{
    Body updatedBodyContent = 
        new Body(newWordContent.DocumentElement.InnerXml);
    output.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body = updatedBodyContent;
    output.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
}
response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(outputPath, 
                                                    FileMode.Open, 
                                                    FileAccess.Read));
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");

response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = outputPath;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because the process which is writing to the file has an exclusive lock on it. You need to close `output` prior to trying to open it. Your second param in the `Open` call is saying you're opening for editing, apparently that is locking the file. You could move that code outside of the using statement which will automatically dispose of the lock.

Answer (score -1):

At line 3, you open the file to edit

```
WordprocessingDocument.Open(outputPath, true)
```

But at line 8, you try to open it again

```
new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
```

You can close your `using` before setting your response headers.

Comment: On line 3 he opens the file to edit. If he was opening to read line 8 would work.